# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference when running tests

Tags: go

I know there are similar questions out there, but in this case we don't have to do with an initialised variable.

Within `pkg/cluster`, I have 3 files:

- `cluster.go` where is the business code
- `cluster_test.go` with my tests
- `cluster_test_mocks.go` with a lot of pre-initialized values to be used for mocking.

I am mainly mocking structures used in the google go sdk.

I have a mock type acting as a container for several functions relying on go sdk library,

```golang
type MockGcloudProvider struct{}
```

and several (package scoped) structs initialised which act as mock responses from go sdk.

```golang
import  crm "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1"

var mockedResourceId1 = crm.ResourceId{
    Id: "1122334455",
}

var mockedResourceId2 = crm.ResourceId{
    Id: "1122334455",
}
```

and here is a method mocking the above responses:

```golang
func (mgcloudProvider *MockGcloudProvider) GetProjectOrganization(ctx context.Context, crmProject crm.Project) (*crm.ResourceId, error) {
    var crmRsrId *crm.ResourceId
    switch crmProject.Name {
    case "project_1":
    case "project_2":
        crmRsrId = &mockedResourceId1
    case "project_3":
    case "project_4":
        crmRsrId = &mockedResourceId2
    }
    return crmRsrId, nil
    //return nil, errors.New("ERROR while mocking get project organization")
}
```

When the last function is injected and called from my main code when running tests, it causes segment violation error:

```
▶ go test -v -run TestMock
=== RUN   TestMock1
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x14afe45]

goroutine 25 [running]:
github.com/myrepo/mytool/pkg/cluster.Count.func1(0x16b3f40, 0x1a61fc0, 0x16b3d40, 0xc0000a6010, 0x15f3eba, 0x10, 0xc0001d46c0, 0xc
0000a6c10, 0xc0000a6c20, 0xc0001d4690, ...)
        /Users/panteliskaramolegkos/Workspace/mytool/pkg/cluster/cluster.go:111 +0x1d5
created by github.com/myrepo/mytool/pkg/cluster.Count
        /Users/panteliskaramolegkos/Workspace/mytool/pkg/cluster/cluster.go:105 +0x487
exit status 2
FAIL    github.com/myrepo/mytool/pkg/cluster   0.538s
```

Here is the actual business code invocation:

```golang
projects, err := gcp.ListProjects(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("ERROR: Unable to list projects")
    }
    wg.Add(len(projects))
    for _, v := range projects {
        go func(project crm.Project) {
            parentOrganization, err := gcp.GetProjectOrganization(ctx, project)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("ERROR retrieving parent organization for: ", project, err)
            }
            if org != "all" {
                if organizatonMap[parentOrganization.Id] != org {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
            }
(goroutine continues...)
```

I know its complicated, just taking the long shot that anyone makes out of sth of this mess...

Comment: It is likely that project name is neither "project_2" nor "project_4", so `parentOrganization` is nil.

Comment: "In this case we don't have to do with an initialised variable." Yeah, you do. Otherwise the error wouldn't occur. Did you mean to put [`fallthrough` statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements) into your empty case blocks?

Comment: @Peter for multiple case values for the same block you can just use a comma.

`case "project_1", "project_2":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter is right, you need `fallthrough` statements on cases *project_1* and *project_3*. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/ts2CVoQfcc1

You could also change the `GetProjectOrganization` function to initialize a local variable instead of a pointer to a local variable for default cases. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/iG3mLQA-vTG

Comment: There's no need to use fallthrough. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The switch statement in Go behaves differently to C and related languages. So

```
    case "project_1":
    case "project_2":
        // do something
```

means that for the project_1 case nothing is done, which in other languages (which I suspect you are familiar with) is like:

```
    case "project_1":
        break;
    case "project_2":
        /* do something */
        break;
```

Do it this way:

```
    switch crmProject.Name {
    case "project_1", "project_2":
        crmRsrId = &mockedResourceId1
    case "project_3", "project_4":
        crmRsrId = &mockedResourceId2
    default:
        // maybe handle this by returning an error
    }
```